# Selecting item from a dropdown with javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is a dropdown menu of a website

```
    <select name="ctl00$ddlWersjeJezykowe" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ddlWersjeJezykowe\',\'\')', 0)" id="ddlWersjeJezykowe" style="width:100px;margin-right: 10px;">
                <option selected="selected" value="1">Polska</option>
                <option value="2">English</option>
                <option value="17">Русская</option>
                <option value="19">Українська</option>
                <option value="20">Deutsch</option>
                <option value="21">Français</option>
                <option value="22">Español</option>
                <option value="24">Português</option>
                <option value="25">Türk</option>
</select>
```

I want to change the language to English through browser console. I tried this on my console

```
document.getElementById("ddlWersjeJezykowe").value="2";
```

It only selects English but doesn't change the language. How can i change the language to English through my browser console?

Comment: Call the __doPostBack function too.

Comment: Please give me a example. Accually i'm newbie in javascript

Comment: ?? After changing the value of the select element, write  `__doPostBack('ctl00$ddlWersjeJezykowe','');` to the console and press ENTER.

Comment: Already tried before posting here. doesn't work :( Here is the site link where i tried
https://secure.e-konsulat.gov.pl/

Comment: Try my answer it works

Comment: @MDAlJummanShithil Try again, it seems to work fine. Also Twisting's answer works after you've changed the value of the select element.

Comment: None of those are working :( Please run your code on that site then you'll find it's not working

Comment: We actually did and found it's working... please type `document.getElementById("ddlWersjeJezykowe").value="2"`then enter, then `document.getElementById("ddlWersjeJezykowe").onchange()` then enter

Answer (score 0):

Changing the value programmatically doesn't fire the `onchange` event, so you have to call `setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ddlWersjeJezykowe\',\'\')', 0)` too.

Alternatively, you can call `document.getElementById("ddlWersjeJezykowe").onchange()`

Answer (score 0):

This is will get the **selected** value from select dropdown

```
<select id="language" style="width:100px;margin-right: 10px;">
                <option selected="selected" value="1">Polska</option>
                <option value="2">English</option>
                <option value="17">Русская</option>
                <option value="19">Українська</option>
                <option value="20">Deutsch</option>
                <option value="21">Français</option>
                <option value="22">Español</option>
                <option value="24">Português</option>
                <option value="25">Türk</option>
</select>
```

```
function GetValue() {
    var e = document.getElementById("language");
    var result = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}

<button type="button" onclick="GetValue()">Get Selected Value</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```